# Making the X_axis more visible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code I used, the goal is to visualize the evolution of covid in north africa

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
covid <- read.csv("owid-covid-data.csv")
covid
covid %>%
  filter(location %in% c("Tunisia", "Morocco", "Libya")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y= new_cases,color = location, group = location)) +
  geom_line()
```

This is the dataset I used[image: dataset]

as you can see the X_axis is day-to-day therefore it's a bit condensed dataset

And this is the plot[image: plot]

you can't see anything in the X_axis, I want to be able to discern the dates maybe use weeks or months to scale instead of days plot.

r

Comment: what does `class(covid$date)` return please?

Comment: @user20650 string

Comment: okay; if you xconvert it to a date it will be easier to plot. for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018187/changing-tick-intervals-when-x-axis-values-are-dates/30020683#30020683

Comment: Pipe `filter(.) %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date))`. Then add `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months", date_labels = "%b %Y")`.

Comment: You need to convert your character date value to a proper Date vector in R to get more useful axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted string columns to date type as the comments suggested and it all worked out

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
covid <- read.csv("owid-covid-data.csv")
covid
covid %>%
  filter(location %in% c("Tunisia", "Morocco", "Libya")) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y= new_cases,color = location, group = location)) +
  geom_line()
```

this is the plot after modification.
[image: plot]